# Powershell script to get machine uptime by organizational unit

Tags: powershell

I have found a few scripts, but nothing that works, and trying to combine them, failed miserably. I couldn't find anything that could explain how to make the ones I found do what I wanted, So here is my attempt, but it does not work so I was wondering if anyone could help me get it working? *I removed identifying Domain information*

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -like "*" } -SearchBase "OU=OU,DC=DC,DC=DC" |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name |
    Sort-Object |
    Get-WmiObject  -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
$wmi.ConvertToDateTime($wmi.LocalDateTime) - $wmi.ConvertToDateTime($wmi.LastBootUpTime)
```

Answer (score 2):

So you have a couple steps:

1. Get the machine list

   ```
   $list = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "*"' -SearchBase 'OU=Computers,DC=example,DC=com'
   ```
2. Iterate the list

   ```
   $results = foreach ($pc in $list.Name)
   {
   ```
3. Grab the `WMI` information

   ```
       $wmi = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $pc -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
   ```
4. Calculate uptime

   ```
       $uptime = $wmi.ConvertToDateTime($wmi.LocalDateTime) - $wmi.ConvertToDateTime($wmi.LastBootUpTime)
   ```
5. Output the information in a collection you can work with

   ```
       [pscustomobject]@{
           ComputerName = $pc
           Uptime       = $uptime.Hours
       }
   }
   ```

Subtracting two `datetime` objects will give you a `timespan`, so you need to figure out how granular you want that information (seconds, minutes, etc.).  The end result of this process is an array of objects in `$results` with the `ComputerName` and `Uptime`.